# How set scroll_size to _update_by_query request from JAVA API

Tags: elasticsearch

I found this documentation about "update by query" request

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-update-by-query.html

Question is: How add URL parameter to "_update_by_query" query:

The example I add:

pre_production/_update_by_query?slices=200&scroll_size=1000

How add this 2 parameters (slices, scroll_size) usign JAVA Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder` instance in order to modify the number of slices:

```
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder updateByQuery =
  UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);
updateByQuery.source("source_index")
    .source()
    .setSlices(200);                 <--- set the number of slices
```

However, to change the `scroll_size` parameter you need to access the underlying `UpdateByQueryRequest` instance as the builder doesn't have any `setBatchSize()` method. You can do it like this:

```
((UpdateByQueryRequest) updateByQuery.getRequest()).setBatchSize(1000);
```

Comment: updateByQuery = updateByQuery.source(indexName)
                .filter(boolQuery)
                .script(script)
                .setSlices(200);

        ((UpdateByQueryRequest) updateByQuery.getRequest()).setBatchSize(1000);

Like this?

Comment: If that compiles yes :-)